# Как правильно реализовать nested или hierarchical Many-To-Many связи для Mysql и php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel, eloquent

В моем проекте меня есть сущность **статьи**. Каждая статья может принадлежать нескольким разделам. Это легко реализуется подходом many-to-many.

```
    Articles
    id | name
    Categories
    id | name
    Article_categories
    id | article_id | category_id
```

Но мне необходимо добавить к сушностям подразделы, с учетом того что статья может принадлежать нескольким подразделам. В простом видл это можно было бы реализовать двумя дополнительными таблицами.

```
    Subcategories
    id | name
    Article_subcategoires
    id | article_id | subcategories_id
```

А вот теперь вопрос. Мне надо получать данные "иерархическим" способом:

- получить все статьи
- получить все статьи / определенной категории / всех подкатегорий
- получить все статьи / определенной категории / определенной подкатегории
- получить все статьи / всех категорий / определенной подкатегории

и тут моих знаний и практики не уже нехватает, а двойной подход many-to-many не работает, вернее результать получен, но не уверен в его правильности и эффективности с точки зрения ресурсов.

Велосипед на laravel 5.3

```
     ArticleController.php

     $articles = Article::Published()
        ->ByCategory($cat)
        ->BySubcategory($subcat)
        ->paginate(10); 

     Article.php Model
     public function scopeByCategory($query, $catRequest){
             if($catRequest && $catRequest != 'all'  ) {
                 return $query->with('categories')
                     ->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($catRequest) {
                         $q->where('id', $catRequest);
                     });
             }else{
                 return $query;
             }
         }

     public function scopeBySubcategory($query, $subcatRequest){
             if($subcatRequest && $subcatRequest != 'all'  ) {
                 return $query->with('subcategories')
                     ->whereHas('subcategories', function ($q) use ($subcatRequest) {
                         $q->where('id', $subcatRequest);
                     });
             }else{
                 return $query;
             }
         }
```

Но у меня стойкое ощущение что это не правильно, и это велосипед. Есть ли другие решения на уровне проектирования базы или обработки данных в php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Articles a
-- 1 , Categories c   , Article_categories a_c
-- 2 , Subcategories s, Article_subcategoires a_s
WHERE 1=1
-- 1 AND a.id = a_c.article_id AND a_c.category_id      = c.id AND c.name IN (@c_name_csv)
-- 2 AND a.id = a_s.article_id AND a_s.subcategories_id = s.id AND s.name IN (@s_name_csv)
```

Раскомментировать 1, если нужны определённые категории.

Раскомментировать 2, если нужны определённые субкатегории.

Если хочется универсального запроса - раскомментировать всё и дополнить условия до чего-нибудь вроде

```
AND ((c.name IN (@c_name_csv)) OR (@c_name_csv = ''))
```

PS. Не понимаю, почему категории и **суб**категории. По описанию - они полностью независимы.

Comment: спасибо! В структуре DB это отдельные независимые сущности. Попробую описать как это выглядит на сайте. Например статья "Lorem" может принадлежать категории "A-Category" и "B-Category", а так же принадлежать подкатегориям "a-subcat" и "b-subcat". Но пользователи должны видеть ее по адресам  1) articles/all 2) articles/a-category/all-subcategory и articles/b-category/all-subcategory  3) articles/a-category/all-subcategory 4) articles/a-category/a-subcat и articles/a-category/b-subcat и т д. Наверное мутно немного мутно объясняю. Просто другой структуры DB не пришло в голову.

Comment: Просто пытался нагуглить другой вариант структуры DB, возможно с денормализацией - безуспешно, а все примеры в сети однотипны

Comment: @OlegKruglov Тогда почему subcategory? Что, у англов слов мало? type, class, etc...

Comment: @ akina да, блин ))),  это условное название, в проекте у меня это вообще называеться systems и sections, потому что сайт медицинский и статья может принадлежать системам органов, например и условно, голова и живот, и секциям - анатомия и патология. Просто что бы не засорять эфир я переименовал сущности в более ходовые. Другой вопрос, на уровне организации DB это нормальная структура?

Comment: Да нормальная, чо... есть сущность, есть у неё два каких-то мультиатрибута, независимых.